# rust - JVM не читает параметры

Tags: windows, rust

Я хочу передать в параметры процесса `Command::new()` путь к библиотеке java с кириллицей, но мне выдаёт ошибку JVM:

```
Unrecognized option: --module-path "D:\╨рсюўшщ ёЄюы\fe\lib\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib"
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
program was crashed!: exit code: 1
```

Код программы:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("java")
        .args(&["--module-path", "D:\\Рабочий стол\\fe\\lib\\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\\lib", "--add-modules", "javafx.controls,javafx.fxml", "-jar", "FilesEngine.jar"])
        .status()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");

    if output.success() {
        println!("program closed successfully!");
    } else {
        println!("program was crashed!: {output}");
    }
}
```

Comment: В первую очередь у вас тут проблема не в кириллице, а том, что вы название параметра и значение параметра запихнули в один аргумент, хотя пробел между ними намекает, что они должны быть двумя отдельными аргументами

Comment: А после этого во вторую очередь всплывёт неуместное использование кавычек, которые были бы нужны для экранирования аргументов в командном интерпретаторе, но здесь совершенно не нужны

Comment: И лишь после всего этого только в третью очередь могут всплыть проблемы с кириллицей, но это не точно

Comment: спасибо, я исправил

Comment: @adisteyf у вас код после исправления заработал? Если да, то почему исправленный вариант всё ещё находится в вопросе, а не в ответе?

Comment: Верните код в вопросе как было, а исправленный код добавьте в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) мне помог, я поставил аргументы правильно и убрал кавычки там где был путь, после этого никаких проблем не было.

Comment: @adisteyf, вместо "спасибо" укажите лучше, что конкретно вы исправили по совету, полученному в комментарии, и как выглядит рабочий вариант -- это будет нормальным ответом